# How can I install dirtytalk on Miktex?

Tags: packages, miktex

Tried using the Pacakge Manager, but the package doesn't show.

Comment: According to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dirtytalk the package is not available in MikTeX. Maybe it's a license thing. Alternatively you could try the great [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes). It seems to offer similar things (and maybe even more). If you really want `dirtytalk`, you can install the package manually with the files you get from CTAN, see [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864).

Answer (score 2):

On MiKTeX, after  you've unzipped  `dirtytalk.zip` in  some directory, you'll have to compile the file `dirtytalk.ins` to produce `dirtytalk.sty`.

To make  it useable, if you made an installation for all users, create a TeXMFlocal directory (*not* in MiKTeX roots) if not already done, and declare as `root`with `MiKTeX Settings(Admin), Root tab`, with the  `Add…` button, like this:
[image]

Then copy `dirtytalk.sty` in `TeXMFlocal\tex\latex\dirtytalk\`, and `dirtytalk.pdf` in `TeXMFlocal\latex\doc\dirtytalk\`.

Finally, refresh the FNDB (under `General`  tab).

If you made a per-user installation do the same with `MiKTeX Settings`.

Answer (score 1):

It is available on TeXLive but not MikTeX. You will have to download the ZIP and install it manually. See [this.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dirtytalk)