# Dirtytalk's \say for quoting doesn't work in captions

Tags: captions, quoting

The quotation command `\say` from the [dirtytalk](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/dirtytalk/dirtytalk.pdf) package doesn't seem to work in figure captions. Does anyone know why this is the case and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\begin{document}

    Say is working \say{fine} here.
    
\begin{figure}
    \caption{But it \say{doesn't} work here.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Manually inserting the correct quotation marks `“` and `”` works fine though. But shouldn't `\say` produce the same result?
[image]

Comment: Using cprotect there works. (no idea why.)

Comment: There are questions about caption not accepting fragile stuff https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110831/250119 but none about `\say` being verbatim-like in particular. Duplicate?

Comment: Actually cprotect isn't necessary, just normal protect works. Fragile command.

Comment: "fragile command in moving argument" eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package does

```
\providecommand{\say}[1]{...}
```

and the used code cannot survive in moving arguments.

I'm not sure what's the purpose of `\providecommand`, but anyway you need to make the command robust.

Either use `\protect\say{text}` in captions or section titles, or add

```
\MakeRobust{\say}
```

in the preamble (after loading `dirtytalk`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Another why to get around this is to use the [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)  package instead of `dirtytalk` and replace all `\say` commands by `\enquote` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329786/how-can-i-install-dirtytalk-on-miktex#comment807957_329786).

The `\enquote` command works in captions by default.

`csquotes` has more functionality and is also included in the [MikTex](https://miktex.org) unlike `dirtytalk`. I stopped using `dirtytalk` because of this.

Comment: Any idea why miktex does not include dirtytalk? (I agree on csquotes btw)

Comment: @daleif No clue. I asked the [question](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/1098#discussion-4059768) on the Miktex-Repo. Maybe we'll get some answers :).